# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\sin{3\pi x}}$ without L'Hopital's rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need help finding this limit:

> $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\sin{3\pi x}}$$

I've thought of dividing and multiplying the numerator by $\pi x$ and the denominator by $3\pi x$ but it doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

Note that I'm not really familiar with L'Hopital's rule as of now, so any answers which do not include it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered expanding the denominator with a trig identity? If you're trying to solve without L'Hospital's rule then that seems like the cleanest try

Comment: @Marcos Actually that is a good idea which leads to a pretty nice solution, thanks for the suggestion. I'd still hold that the trig identity method is a bit more elementary though, since the method I came up with using the special limit involves a couple substitutions

Comment: remember what happens when lim(sina / sin b) when approach zero .. is it just a/b ? :))

Comment: @Bulbasaur Well first off this isn't the limit as $x$ approaches zero. Second off this question would be more interested in showing *why* that's the case rather than just saying that it's the case

Comment: @StephenDonovan I've tried using $sin2x=2sinxcosx$. Can't think of any other identity to use in this case.

Comment: Try using that along with $\sin(a + b) = \sin a\cos b + \cos a\sin b.$ If you do it right you should be able to factor out a $\sin(\pi x)$

Comment: @downmath , it's really easy. Use the formula $\sin3\theta=3\sin\theta- 4\sin^3{\theta}$ and see the magic.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Also fair, although I had aimed to avoid using that formula because it's not as widely taught, and get there by way of the sum formula (as Bonnaduck did)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$

We have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\sin{3\pi x}}&=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\sin(2\pi x+\pi x)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\color{red}{\sin(2\pi x)}\cos(\pi x)+\cos(2\pi x)\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\color{red}{2\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)}\cos(\pi x)+\cos(2\pi x)\sin(\pi x)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{2\cos(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)+\cos(2\pi x)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\cos(\pi)\cos(\pi)+\cos(2\pi)}\\
&=\frac13
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\sin{3\pi x}}$

$=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{3\sin{\pi x}-4 \sin^3\pi x}$

$=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{\frac{3\sin{\pi x}-4 \sin^3{\pi x}}{\sin{\pi x}}}$

$=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{3-4 \sin^2(\pi x) }$

$=\frac{1}{3}$

Use,  $\theta =\pi x $ in the formula
$\sin3\theta=3\sin\theta- 4\sin^3{\theta}$

Answer (score 0):

Since full answers have already been posted, I figured that it would be nice to show an alternative method which I believe was closer to your original attempt.

If the limit involved $x$ approaching $0$ rather than $1,$ then there are algebraic manipulations we could do to put the limit in terms of the special limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1.$ Thankfully, where defined this function is periodic with period $1$ (as the following manipulation will demonstrate) so we can achieve this with the substitution $u = x - 1 \leftrightarrow x = u + 1,$ and $u \to 0$:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{\sin (3\pi x)} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi u + \pi)}{\sin(3\pi u + 3\pi)} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{-\sin(\pi u)}{-\sin(3 \pi u)} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi u)}{\sin(3 \pi u)}$$

taking advantage of the identity $\sin(\theta + \pi) = -\sin(\theta).$

Now we can proceed by rewriting the numerator and denominator in the form $\sin(\theta)/\theta.$

$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi u)}{\sin(3 \pi u)} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi u)}{\sin(3 \pi u)} \cdot \frac{3\pi u}{\pi u} \cdot \frac13 = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi u)/(\pi u)}{\sin(3 \pi u)/(3\pi u)} \cdot \frac13$$

Now, supposing for the moment that the limits all exist and that the denominator doesn't go to zero, we can split the limit over division as follows:

$$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi u)/(\pi u)}{\sin(3 \pi u)/(3\pi u)} \cdot \frac13 = \frac13 \cdot \frac{\lim_{u \to 0} \sin(\pi u)/(\pi u)}{\lim_{u \to 0} \sin(3\pi u)/(3\pi u)}$$

Now consider the substitutions $v_1 = \pi u$ and $v_2 = 3 \pi u$ for the numerator and denominator respectively. We now have

$$\frac13 \cdot \frac{\lim_{v_1 \to 0} \sin(v_1)/(v_1)}{\lim_{v_2 \to 0} \sin(v_2)/(v_2)} = \frac13 \cdot \frac11 = \boxed{\frac13}$$

As I indicated before, this approach is a bit more involved than the substitution, but I still find it pretty elegant and I thought you might like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$f=\frac{\sin{(\pi x)}}{\sin{(3\pi x})}$$

$$x=y+1 \implies f=\frac{\sin{(\pi y)}}{\sin{(3\pi y})}=\frac 13\times\frac{\sin{(\pi y)}}{\pi y}\times\frac{3\pi y}{\sin{(3\pi y)}}$$ and $y \to 0$. Remember a very simple limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{x \to {1}} \frac{\sin{\pi{x}}}{\sin{3\pi{x}}}.
$$
To solve this problem I recommend to use the **Taylor series**:
$$
\sin(x)=\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+....\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
.\tag{1}
$$
$$
\sin({\alpha}+{\pi})=-\sin({\alpha}).
\tag{2}
$$
As **Mr. Leibovici** said, we need to perform a substitution $x=(y+1)$, therefore, $y\to{0}$.

Using the very well known formula $(2)$ and the substitution $x=(y+1)$ relatively our problem, therefore, we will have:
$$
\lim_{y\to{0}} \frac{\sin{\pi{y}}}{\sin{3\pi{y}}}=\lim_{y\to{0}} \frac{\left(\pi{y}-\frac{(\pi{y})^3}{3!}+\frac{(\pi{y})^5}{5!}+\frac{(\pi{y})^7}{7!}+....\right)}{\left(3\pi{y}-\frac{(3\pi{y})^3}{3!}+\frac{(3\pi{y})^5}{5!}+\frac{(3\pi{y})^7}{7!}+....\right)}=
\\
=\lim_{y\to{0}}\frac{y\left(\pi-\frac{\pi^{3}y^{2}}{3!}+\frac{\pi^{5}y^{4}}{5!}+\frac{\pi^{7}y^{6}}{7!}+....\right)}{y\left(3\pi-\frac{(3\pi)^{3}y^{2}}{3!}+\frac{(3\pi)^{5}y^{4}}{5!}+\frac{(3\pi)^{7}y^{6}}{7!}+....\right)}=\lim_{y\to{0}}\frac{\pi}{3\pi}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to {1}} \frac{\sin{\pi{x}}}{\sin{3\pi{x}}}=\frac{1}{3}.
$$